# Скролл блоков как в вк

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите как организовать скролл блоков как в вк
вот такой структуры

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="wrap_left"></div>
        <div class="wrap_right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить. Добавьте изображение с желаемым результатом.

Answer (score 1):

В ВК желаемый эффект при скролле достигается за счет неслабого js-кода, и оперирования с `position: fixed/absolute` и отступами у блоков. Минусов у такого решения хватает:

1. При горизонтальном скроллинге блоки перемещаются рывками;
2. Не самая лучшая производительность из-за привязки js-кода к событию `on scroll`;
3. Нюансы на touch устройствах, в корректном отлове `on scroll` события и в позиционировании блоков.

С другой же стороны - какая у вас конечная цель? Сделать некоторые блоки приклеивающимися к экрану при скроллинге.

И для этого есть элементарный в использовании, стабильный и браузерно-ускоренный способ: `position: sticky;`.

1. С ним вам не потребуется писать js-код, совсем;
2. Это свойство [поддерживают современные браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky);
3. В IE, Edge и Android Browser - блоки просто не будут приклеиваться, верстка никак не поедет и не выйдет из строя;
4. В крайнем случае для решения пункта 3 есть [полифилл](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill);
5. Отлично работает с горизонтальным скроллингом;
6. Отлично работает на touch устройствах.

Единственное НО - блоки не будут так эффектно замирать и скроллиться вверх при обратном скроллинге. Но - плюсы `position: sticky`, по моему мнению, перевешивают этот единственный минус.